# Has anyone tried using a via as a receptacle for pogo pins?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, edge-connector, pogo-pins

I am in need of building a lowcost magnetic board to board connector.
There will be a lot of modules and a connector that connects both sides is needed 6x on each pcb.

I need a connection similar to this - 5x pogo pins on one side, 5 receptacles on the other side.

[image: Board to board pogo pins]

Has anyone tried using plated through-hole vias (castellated holes) as receptacles (female side) of a pogo pin? On top of that the pogo pins would need to be embedded in the pcb to be in the same height.

Thanks for comments, if this is a really bad idea.

[image]

I have something like these pictures in mind:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a via instead of a typical test point (a circular pad without a hole)?

Comment: Never tried it... I could see it working, but you'd need your boards to be intentionally misaligned in the assembly. I've never seen mid-board-mount pogo pins. I suppose Mill-Max would make them for you if you're willing to buy enough of them...

Comment: I want to use it as a kind of right angle connector. I think I would be able to use normal pogo pins soldered inside a pcb.

Comment: and I would't need to misalign the pogo pins. If a choose a pin that is close to 1.6mm in height, it can be soldered inside the height of a pcb.

Comment: It's probably possible with castellated holes and plated slots to accept the pogo pins (and a jig to align them during hand soldering). The spacing would be relatively large. Reliable? Who knows.

Comment: Via's are created by a plating process and are made of very soft copper - i.e. it doesn't take much to tear them up. I wouldn't chance it. Also, pogo pins aren't really intended for 'permanent' connections at all. They're for use in manufacturing to perform tests on the board. I think what you're suggesting is using them as a substitute for a real connector. I would not entertain that idea if this is for a mass-produced product. Are you sure the first picture (the mill-max thing) are pogo pins???

Comment: The spring force on pogo pins is usually much higher than the spring force for the type of pins shown in your first picture. Might make for a connector that pops off easily with magnets.

Comment: So... if I wanted to use something similar to pogo pins as a permanent connector, is there something else?
For example batteries in phones use spring connectors or spring fingers for emi shielding are in use for a long time. I saw some products that use pogo pins in a similar fasion - for example Roli Blocks.